# Draw sprite from one side of screen to appear on the opposite side

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I know this is a lot of code to get working, but I already have it working from left to right and top to bottom successfully. The trouble is when I try to add it the opposite way in the sprite just moves crazily up and down super fast. I don't understand why

this is what my if statement looks like, just a small example of it.

```
if (Player1_Rect.Left <= Screen_Bounds.Left)
{
    Sprite_1Position.X = Screen_Bounds.Right;
    float Random_Y_Axis = r.Next(0, Screen_Height);
    Sprite_1Position.Y = Random_Y_Axis;
    //this works as I want it to.
}

if (Player1_Rect.Right <= Screen_Bounds.Right)
{
    Sprite_1Position.X = Screen_Bounds.Left;
    float Random_Y_Axis = r.Next(0, Screen_Height);
    Sprite_1Position.Y = Random_Y_Axis;
    //this messes everything up.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this if statement: `if (Player1_Rect.Right <= Screen_Bounds.Right)`. What you really want is if the left of the player rectangle is **greater** than the right of the viewport, not less. The reason you would use the left of the player instead of the right of the player is because you want the player to be completely off screen before they appear on the left again. Your fixed code would be:

```
if (Player1_Rect.Left >= Screen_Bounds.Right)
```

Comment: ahhh darn. your right it works now like i wanted it to.

Comment: i tried if (Player1_Rect.Tight>= Screen_Bounds.Right) but that didnt do anything, for whatever reason i never thought of changing the rect from right to left....